# Save and play pure 20kHz signals (sound) [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, audio, wav, frequency, speaker

I'm trying to save (as .WAV) and play 20kHz pure signals (short and long signals) but as I see at the visualizer, I didn't receive what I really need.

As you can see this is the WAV file inspection, I send 20kHz but there are more noises below.

Also, I use a 20kHz dedicated speaker and when I transmit the 20kHz I hear ticks that I don't want to hear (maybe because of the noises or because of the sin signal that i send wrong)

The spectrogram that is attached to the post is the pure WAV file that I write the sin signals in there, before the transmission (via special speaker)

[image]

1. At the lower frequency, I still receive these noises
2. I want 20kHz in purpose, I know that I can't hear this frequency so because of this I use a special microphone and speaker (+with spectrogram) to inspect what I transmit.
   I just don't understand why I receive these noises below the frequency that I transmit, maybe it's because I sending the 'sin' signal like this?

```
freq=20000;                                                                
time=3000;                                                                 
Fs=48000; 
                                                               
timevec = (0:1/Fs:time-(1/Fs));                                            
short = sin(2*pi*freq*timevec(1:7000));                                  
long = sin(2*pi*freq*timevec(1:20000));   
                                 
%%
%.
%.
%Here i put the signals in array to send them at the order that i want
%.
%.
%%

pp = audioplayer(array,Fs);                                                  
play(pp);                                                                  
filename = 'sound.wav';                                                    
audiowrite(filename,array,Fs);
```

Comment: 1. There is no such thing as "pure 20kHz" if you sample the recording in finite fixed time intervals, toying with the sampling rate sometimes changes the spectrum a bit. 2. The "tick" is likely due to a very fast amplitude rising edge in the signal. Fade-in helps, at the cost of temporal precision.

Comment: @wwweagle thank you for your comment. there is any way that I can transmit 20kHz-22kHz frequencies? Did I think maybe the SIN signal makes these noises and ticks? what do you suggest?

Comment: I found a [link](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Spectrum_Analysis_Sinusoids.html) that helps to explain things, but not directly solve them. To reproduce an ideal signal in the real world is an engineering challenge that some trade-off and tolerance are going to be made.